# Amazon S3: Object key name with logical hierarchy that includes bucket name

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an s3 bucket `bucket_name` and my api creates a presigned url, returned to the user, for uploading an object to s3. The url created has the following format:

```
https://bucket_name.s3.region.amazonaws.com/<bucket_name>/<project_id>/<object_id>/<object_name>?other_aws_specific=params
```

As you can see, I want to store the object in the <bucket_root>/project_id/object_id/ directory.
However, this creates an actual logical directory that I can see in the bucket console on s3 with name `bucket_name`. (see attached ss)

Other cloud providers usually store the object at <bucket_root>/project_id/object_id/ if such a bucket path is provided.

If I remove the <bucket_name> from the presigned url, it will break the api because GCS and Azure blob store work just fine with that url structure.

I'm expecting S3 to store the object at the bucket root, see the attached ss of the path it creates as of now.

[This page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/object-keys.html) does not state any information for this edge case.

[image: s3 object hierarchy]

Comment: You have the bucket name both as part of the domain and as part of the path. Having it as part of the domain is the "correct" way, therefore you need to remove it from the path segment. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/VirtualHosting.html

Comment: Thanks @luk2302, so I removed the bucket name from path segment by setting `awsClient.withPathStyleAccessEnabled(false)`. However (I think unrelated), I now get `SignatureDoesNotMatch` error from s3. Not exactly sure why it starts to work as soon as I set the value to true above. My bucket permissions remain exactly the same.

Comment: Yes, this removes it from the path, not the domain. The domain is still `bucket_name.s3.region.amazonaws.com`